# Android Scale Animation with bounce interpolator

Tags: android, android-animation

I am doing a scale animation with `anim xml` as follows. The animation interpolator isn't working. I am trying to have bounce interpolator but isn't working.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="900"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="0.5"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
     </set>
```

EDIT:
Actually my whole xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<scale
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

<alpha
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Finally got the solution. It works for me and could be helpful to others. The key was to put the android:interpolator tag in the animation set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator" >

<scale
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

<alpha
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

Comment: lol, if I had known you had two animations... Anyway, your answer is fine, accept it to make it more clear for other users.

Comment: @Snicolas any idea why interpolator doesn't work in animation when its given in docs <http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:interpolator>

Comment: Can you show the result of the animation?
Im starting in this area of animation and i would like to see some examples.

Comment: @GauravVashisth : in this the animation start from top. What i need is from bottom. I tried many but didn't work.

Comment: Better one thanks.    Animation myAnim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce2); btn_singup.startAnimation(myAnim2);

Comment: You can also control the bounce with a custom interpolator see this guide: http://evgenii.com/blog/spring-button-animation-on-android/

Comment: The question is about "bounce interpolator" but should give a chance to "overshoot_interpolator". I think, it looks better with this animation set.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to have different interpolators for your animations in the animation set, set the `shareInterpolator` attribute to false like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
```

And then set an interpolator in each animation element. Apparently, `shareInterpolator` is set to true by default.

Comment: I was stuck with this problem for hours, I couldn't understand why we could use individual attributes for everything except interpolators and the explanation is because it is true by default, just like this answer pointed out.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

try to add a duration :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<scale 
  android:fromXScale="1"
  android:fromYScale="0.5"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="0%"
  android:toXScale="1.0"
  android:toYScale="1.0"
  android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

And note that the animation set is useless if it contains only one animation.

Comment: thanks but duration is already there android:duration="900". I am getting the animation to work but there is no bounce effect.

Comment: Did you try to remove the animation set ?

Comment: edited the question, i have also tried by reomoving the alpha and removing the animation set

Answer (score 0):

Bounce is just an animation effect where animation ends in bouncing fashion. For this set android:interpolator value to @android:anim/bounce_interpolator. This bounce can be used with any kind animation. Following slide down example uses bounce effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">

<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```