# How to set custom animation to design library BottomSheetDialogFragment android

Tags: android, android-support-design, bottom-sheet

I am stuck with animation. I set [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14117160/5710872) animation to support library MyBottomSheetDialogFragment

I try

```
@Override
    public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
        return super.onCreateAnimation(R.anim.activity_back_in, enter, R.anim.activity_back_out);
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    public void setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.sheet_user_detail, null);
        view.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.activity_back_in));
        dialog.setContentView(view);

        mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());

        mBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
    }
```

Can't work properly.

Comment: Do you find a solution for this?

Comment: I used custom dialog-fragment.

Comment: Could you post the solution? Thanks