# Ola Jumping Pin Animation

Tags: android, animation

I was trying to create animation like Ola Cabs India Splash-screen, where the marker pin keeps jumping. I could create a bouncing animation by searching here and there.

[Android Scale Animation with bounce interpolator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110512/android-scale-animation-with-bounce-interpolator)

But could not recreate the Ola animation. Could anyone help with some guidelines.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you can post how the animation should look like.

Comment: @Christopher ...Hi...i could not find anything near to similar anywhere to provide a reference... not sure if i am allowed to make a video of the animation while running the said app and post.. it is very much lke godslayer_69 answer below but with compatible atleast api 19 or so

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found a solution to my requirement.Posting it for anyone looking for similar solutions.

```
TranslateAnimation transAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,-getDisplayHeight()/10,0);
            transAnim.setStartOffset(500);
            transAnim.setDuration(3000);
            transAnim.setRepeatCount(-1);
            transAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            transAnim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
            transAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                    final int left = image3.getLeft();
                    final int top = image3.getTop();
                    final int right = image3.getRight();
                    final int bottom = image3.getBottom();
                    image3.layout(left, top, right, bottom);

                }
            });
            image3.startAnimation(transAnim);





 private int getDisplayHeight() {
    return this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this article below

[Animation: Jump-through](https://medium.com/google-developers/animation-jump-through-861f4f5b3de4)

The above animation has been done using [animated vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html). This will only work on and above api 25.

Comment: yes,,,it is much like what i was trying to achieve ...but with compatible api lower  than 25 also